# Image gallery with original image proportions

Tags: media

I was looking for a module a tutorial how to create an image gallery in drupal 7 where when you go in album all images are not cropped in rectangulars and displayed in a table, but remain with their natural proportions and displayed in columns as I provided a print screen below(tumblr theme), each image has a unique page with it's caption. I am not sure what is the particular term for such way of displaying images is called so I am asking here

[image: tumblr theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably want the functionality provided by [Masonry API](https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry) and its sub-modules: Masonry Views and Masonry Fields.

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery. Think of it as the
>   flip-side of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements
>   horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically,
>   positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result
>   minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like
>   a mason fitting stones in a wall.

In the view you will specify a image formatter that only sizes on the width so that the height remains proportional.